# Link azure blob storage to computer

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I know this is possible to link Azure blob to our local computer but can't remember how

My goal is to make possible to access blob like it is local disk, for example here i can access to a blob from local desktop

[image]

edit: I don't want to use azure storage explorer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, it's possible using Azure Files. You can mount it using Powershell or map a network drive:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows

EDIT: Full answer:

[image]

[image]

Use the storage account name prepended with AZURE\ as the username and a storage account key as the password:

[image]

Comment: Why not include a full answer? As opposed to linking to pages which might one day become deprecated

Comment: this is the full answer. It's not possible using Blob, but Azure Files. The person knows how to mount it, just was using the wrong service

Comment: FYI most ISPs block port 445 needed for SMB so this is only a viable solution for corp networks or business level internet subscriptions usually

Answer (score 3):

Firstly there is a charge way to mount blob to local, you could refer to this blog: [Use CloudBerry Drive to create a local mapped network drive to Azure Blob Storage](https://arlanblogs.alvarnet.com/use-cloudberry-drive-to-create-a-local-mapped-network-drive-to-azure-blob-storage/).

Except this, you could choose to use [Rclone](https://rclone.org/azureblob/) to implement this. Rclone is a command line program to sync files and directories. However fro now this service could not Run mount as a daemon, means could not mount automatically with system startup.

I mount one container to my local.

[image]

[image]